# git-svn merging between multiple remotes

Tags: git, git-svn

I have git-svn setup to track two remote svn locations, say http://svnserver/develop/project and http://svnserver/release/project .

I also created local branches of the remotes in order to make changes and dcommit to them. However, when I try to merge a change from a local branch of develop to a local branch of release, I get conflicts which needs to be resolved in a text editor.

Example workflow

```
# Setup the repos
git svn init http://svnserver/develop/project -R develop -i svn-develop
git svn init http://svnserver/release/project -R release -i svn-release
git svn fetch develop
git svn fetch release
git checkout svn-release
git checkout -b release
git checkout svn-develop
git checkout -b develop

# Make changes to develop branch and commit to svn
git commit -a -m "Changes"
git svn dcommit

# I'd like to bring changes to release branch
git checkout release
git merge develop --squash

# Ack! Conflicts :<
```

Why can't git simply apply the diff to the release branch? Did I setup my remotes incorrectly? Is it because they are not tracked from a single parent?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you getting svn or git conflicts?

Comment: git conflicts. I think though that the problem is that there just isn't an easy way to do this when I'd like to cherry pick changes from the develop branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, no, you can't do this.

A bit of detail:

Your initial merge problem is because svn-release and svn-develop don't share a parent commit, and git's automatic merging tools simply won't work. You'd have to merge manually and create a commit that they both share as a parent.

The problems don't stop there. Subversion is liner in how it manages commits, and you'll notice that when you do the `git svn dcommit`, your local commits that get pushed are actually re-written after they go into subversion, to reflect the svn revision number. This changes the local git sha1sum of the commit, which is essentially a re-write of history. Re-writing history causes all sorts of issues if you have other local git branches that you merge with, and will continue to run into merging problems down the road.

Basically, if you do your initial merge commit, do more development, and push those changes back up, your merge commit will get re-written, it's sha1sum changed, and your branches will no longer share a parent. You'd starting with the same problem over again each time you want to merge/push.

Answer (score 0):

A longer answer : yes, you can do this, but not trivially.

The circumstance I'm in is that I have two separate SVN repositories that were previously managed with Bazaar. They share a common history (pushed from one repo to the other by Bazaar), but have totally different commit IDs because they were in different repositories, and git-svn rolls repo ID into the commit message, which affects the SHA1.

What they *will* have in common is that their root tree IDs will be the same up to the point at which they diverge - the SHA1 of the tree object will be identical for identical trees.

So my plan is to :

- Retire one or both SVN repositories (I really don't want have to do this again)
- Migrate all revisions into the same Git repository

  1. Clone both trees into different Git repositories
  2. List all the root tree IDs and compare them to find the point at which they diverge.
  3. Create a branch in my target repository at this point
  4. For each subsequent revision in my source repository

     - Check it out in the source repository
     - Replace the tree in the target repository with this tree
     - Commit that revision

I should end up with a single Git repository containing both diverging branches with the correct point of origin. At which point, merging is hopefully a lot easier.